# Knockout js in ASP.net Core 2.1 returns me undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, knockout.js

I have a problem with Kcnockout Js, and when he tries to return the result, he returns it to me undifferentiated, I have verified the contractor and if he is returning me data, as shown in the following image,

[image]

but when loading the list of values ​​in the view it throws me that it is undefined, as I show in the following image,

[image]

I don't know why he sends me that message, this is my controller code,

```
public JsonResult GetGender()
{
    ServiceResult serviceResult = new ServiceResult();

    serviceResult = this._genderServices.GetListGenders();

    return Json(serviceResult);

}
```

This is the view code,

```
<h2>Generos</h2>
<hr />
<p data-bind="visible: IsNewButton">
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: New" class="btn btn-primary">Crear Nuevo</a>
</p>
<div id="divListGenders" data-bind="visible: ShowResult">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Genero
                </th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Genders">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left" data-bind="text: GenderName"></td>
                <td style="text-align:center">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.Edit" class=" btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a> |
                    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.Details" class=" btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a> |
                    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.Delete" class=" btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div data-bind="visible: IsBackToListButton">
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: BackToList" class="btn btn-info">Regresar</a>
</div>
<script src="~/js/Gender.js"></script>
```

This is the method that returns the list of genres,

```
    var LoadListGenders = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/AdminGenders/GetGender',
            data: null,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    genderViewModel.Genders.removeAll();
                    genderViewModel.Genders(data.Data);
                }
                else {
                    alert(data.Data);
                }
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Ocurrión un error, cargando los generos.');
            }
        });

    };

}
```

I provided it on asp.net MVC 5 and it works well, I don't know why it doesn't work for me in ASP.NET Core 2.1, I'd appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ASP.NET Core` the default case for serializing output to `JSON` is camelcase, whereas it was Pascal case for `ASP.NET MVC 5`.

Notice that the first image in your post shows all properties is camelcase:

```
Object { success: true, message: null, data: Array(1) ... }
```

Similar for the items in the `data` array: `genderId`, `genderName`, etc.

One way to solve this is by updating your `javascript` code and `Knockout` bindings by applying camelcase property names.
E.g.

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
        // ....
    }
    else {
        alert(data.data);
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively you can chose to configure your Web API to return Pacalcased JSON, e.g. by having the code below in `Startup` `ConfigureServices`:

```
services
    // ...
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    })
    // ...
```

Comment: my doubt is the following, the properties I have to place them as I show in the first image

Comment: The AddJsonOptions method does not recognize me indicating that services does not have that definition

Comment: Depending on the`.NET Core` version, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728200/how-to-turn-off-or-handle-camelcasing-in-json-response-asp-net-core) shows alternative ways to configure the json options.