# Property 'JsonResult.SerializerSettings' must be an instance of type 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions'

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing a page that shows the webgrid of all values of Leave Type Option (which is a model containing id, LeaveType and status). In my controller, I have written something below.

After I run the code, I got the runtime error

> InvalidOperationException: Property 'JsonResult.SerializerSettings' must be an instance of type 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions'

I tried to google it but I don't understand this issue and I would like to seek advice on how to solve this.

Thank you.

```
public class OptLeaveTypeController : Controller
{
        private readonly theManagerContext _context;

        public OptLeaveTypeController(theManagerContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult GetLeaveTypes()
        {         
                var leaveTypes = _context.OptLeaveType.OrderBy(a => a.LeaveTypeId).ToList();
                return Json(new { data = leaveTypes }, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

Comment: are you using .net core 3.1?

Comment: i am using .net core 3.0. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1) .NET CORE MVC:-**

```
    public IActionResult GetLeaveTypes()
    {         
            var leaveTypes = _context.OptLeaveType.OrderBy(a => a.LeaveTypeId).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = leaveTypes });
    }
```

**OR**

```
    public IActionResult GetLeaveTypes()
    {         
            var leaveTypes = _context.OptLeaveType.OrderBy(a => a.LeaveTypeId).ToList();
            return new JsonResult(new { data = leaveTypes });
    }
```

**2) .NET MVC:-**

```
    public ActionResult GetLeaveTypes()
    {         
            var leaveTypes = _context.OptLeaveType.OrderBy(a => a.LeaveTypeId).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = leaveTypes }, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: just want to ask why the result return the field name starting with lower case? my database field and model name starts with Capital letter such as LeaveTypeId, LeaveType...etc. Thanks

{"data":[{"leaveTypeId":1,"leaveType":"Annual Leave                                      ","status":"1 "},{"leaveTypeId":2,"leaveType":"Sick Leave                                        ","status":"1 "}]}

Comment: @George Now .NET CORE JSON default is now camelCase (which is JSON Convention).  If you need/want all of the JSON output to be in PascalCase, then see --https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728200/how-to-turn-off-or-handle-camelcasing-in-json-response-asp-net-core