# Json setting errors must be an instance of type Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings

Tags: c#, json

Does anyone know what this error is, and what does it mean?

> Property 'JsonResult.SerializerSettings' must be an instance of type
> 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings

I'm developing a .NET 6 app, and I have a method that returns JSON, looks like this:

```
  public IActionResult GetItems()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Item> Items= new List<Item> { };
            foreach (var item in GetItems())
            {
                Items.Add(new Item(
                    item.Id,
                    item.Name,
                    ));
            }

          

            return Json( Items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I've tried the following things:

```
 var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            };

 var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Items);
```

and I would return:

```
 return Json(jsonData,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

A few notes - I did install the Newtonsoft.Json package in my project.

But for some reason I keep getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you see this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61141567/14973743

Comment: Yes still doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: Presumably you got the setup of your asp.net host wrong and mixed up Json.Net and System.Text.Json somehow. Without seeing your setup we can't really help besides guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You should not to serialize data before using return Json, it will serialize your data twice and you will have a problem to deserialize it. Just use OK

```
return Ok( Items);
```