# Angular can't cast results to object - is it IActionResult?

Tags: angular, .net-core, casting

Copied similar to one answered yesterday:
Trying to get a specific 'User' object returned from backend.
Angular:

```
    this.authService.getUserByName(selectedName)
.subscribe( (response: User) => 
                 {  const selectedUser = response;
                    const firstname = selectedUser.FirstName;
                    this.f.FirstName.setValue(firstname); },
            (error) => 
                 { console.log(error); }
          );
```

authService:

```
  getUserByName(name: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = this.cache.StorageGet('baseUrl') + 'auth/user/' + name;
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
```

the backend .netCore

```
[HttpGet("user/{userName}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserbyName(string userName)
{
    User userFromRepo = await _repo.GetUserbyName(userName.ToLower());

    if (userFromRepo == null)
        return BadRequest();

    return Ok(userFromRepo);
}
```

The above Ok(userFromRepo):
[image]

Notice all the field names Capitalized (same as in the database and also in "User" as defined in the frontend and backend).
User class Angular:

```
export class User {
    Id: string;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Phone1: string;
    Phone2: string;
    KnownAs: string;
    EmailAddress: string;
    Username: string;
    PasswordHash: any;
    PasswordSalt: any;
    Question: string;
    Answer: string;
    ProjectAdmin: number;
    SystemAdmin: number;
    }
```

Upon return to the frontend (main function that called the service):
[image]

The fields shown in debugger snapshot are all first letter lowercase.  Not only does:  selectedUser.FirstName show as 'undefined', but selectedUser.firstName will give a compile error (of course).
Thus: the response is not being cast to User?

What am I missing (beside brains, experience, ...)?

Thanks in advance.

Yogi

Comment: Could you show your User model in Angular?

Comment: Hi,  Angular: export class User shown above The backend has this:

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Phone1 { get; set; }
        public string Phone2 { get; set; }
        public string KnownAs { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
  
}

Comment: and      public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public int ProjectAdmin { get; set; }
        public bool SystemAdmin { get; set; }
   }

Should be the same?

Comment: Yes, sorry, why didn't I see it!!

Answer (score 0):

Change the properties in your `User` class to camelCase. For example,

```
export class User {
    id: string;
    firstName: string;
    // and so on
}
```

As your second screenshot shows the API returns the json in camelCase. If you can't change the case and want to continue using PascalCase then you should change your backend to return PascalCase. Depending on your .Net Core version perhaps this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58135043/4552354.

Comment: Following that link... that may be the thing.  I don't want to change the case ... front and backends both are defined the same, but - as your link shows - there is a way to be sure json translations don't mess with it.  I want to try it first, before I mark you answer.  Thanks sooo much.  Will get back later.