# .NET 6 - AddJsonOptions with CamelCase not working

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, system.text.json, jsonserializer

I have tried use camelCase insentive on .NET 6 for deseralize content from API

I configured like this in Startup.cs, but it is not working

```
            .AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
            });
```

I get to solve with this resolution: https://github.com/andre-ss6
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31094#issuecomment-543342051

He recommended using the following code:

```
            ((JsonSerializerOptions)typeof(JsonSerializerOptions)
    .GetField("s_defaultOptions",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(null))
    .PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
```

I tried and worked, but I thought is complex, because it is used reflection, I don't know what to thought, Someone have other solution or a explanation?

I deserialize it like this:

```
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);

        var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<InvestimentFundsResponseData>(content);
```

My class is, how can you saw, I don't use the attribute [JsonPropertyName]

```
    public class InvestimentFundsResponseData
    {
      public IEnumerable<InvestmentFundsResponse> Data { get; set;}
    }

    public class InvestmentFundsResponse
    {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Your code should work, UNLESS you have applied a `[JsonPropertyName]` attribute to the properties, then it doesn't.

Comment: Can you please add minimal repro? Or at least show where and how do you deserialize content.

Comment: I completed the questions with the answer of you question @GuruStron

Comment: There's a thread with a like problem, but I tried some solutions and none workes
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728200/how-to-turn-off-or-handle-
camelcasing-in-json-response-asp-net-core/72033170?noredirect=1#comment127302832_72033170

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JsonSerializer.Deserialize` does not use `JsonSerializerOptions` which are configured by `AddJsonOptions`, create and pass required options manually (possibly resolve ones from the DI via `JsonOptions`):

```
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<InvestimentFundsResponseData>(content, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    Converters = {new JsonStringEnumConverter()},
    IgnoreNullValues = true
});
```

Comment: Perfect!! But anyway, Did exist some way that I can to configure JsonSerializerOptions for the all project?
If else I'll always that have pass as parameter, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, so I removed System.Net.Json 5.0.2 and reinstalled the version 6.0.2 this solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could also make a JsonSerializerOptions singleton and add that to DI:

```
// Add this to the ConfigureServices routine in Startup.cs:
JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
    MaxDepth = 10,
    ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles,
    WriteIndented = true
};
serializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
services.AddSingleton(s => serializerOptions);
```

Then to use, simply inject it into the constructor. That way, one change to the options is carried through all your code.

Note: I updated the options to be compliant with the latest version of System.Text.Json (6.0.9) and added a few that I usually specify. The default MaxDepth is 3, so if you have deeper parent/child relationships than that it'll miss some data.